# error: conflicting types for 'f' and previous declaration of 'f' was here

Tags: c

This code is just a situation that I found in my actual code which is very big so I'm giving this.**here in this code the structure "struct node" is not defined it is defined in another c source file.**

**my c source code:**

```
/* test.c */

  1 #include<stdio.h>
  2 #include "test2.h"
  3
  4 void f(struct node * k)
  5 {
  6   
  7 }
```

**my header file :**

```
/* test2.h */

  1 extern void f(struct node * k);
```

When I compile this code with gcc to create an object file:

```
gcc -w -c test.c
```

I get:

```
test.c:6: error: conflicting types for 'f'
test2.h:1: error: previous declaration of 'f' was here
```

I have given the complete prototype of function `f()`. Why I am getting this error?

Another thing is that when I don't include the header file  **test2.h** in **test.c** and explicitly declare the function prototype in `test.c`, it compiles successfully. Code is below:

```
 /* test.c */

      1 #include<stdio.h>
      2 void f(struct node *k);
      3
      4 void f(struct node * k)
      5 {
      6
      7 }
```

gcc -c -w test.c

No error.

Can you please explain why this time I am not getting an error?

Comment: What version of GCC are you using? With 4.6.1 I also get an error on with your last example (where the prototype and the definition are in the same file) - with or without the `extern`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the `extern` keyword on the prototype (although it's not necessary).

You need a forward declaration for `struct node`:

```
/* test2.h */

struct node;  // <== this

extern void f(struct node * k);
```

Without that forward declaration, the `struct node` inside the function prototype is *local* to that particular function prototype.

So when the compiler sees the definition of `f()` it also sees another *different* local declaration for a `struct node` and thinks that you have a conflicting declaration for `f()`.

See C99 6.9.1 "Scopes of identifiers":

> For each different entity that an identifier designates, the
>   identifier is visible (i.e., can be used) only within a region of
>   program text called its scope. Different entities designated by the
>   same identifier either have different scopes, or are in different name
>   spaces. There are four kinds of scopes: function, file, block, and
>   function prototype. (A function prototype is a declaration of a
>   function that declares the types of its parameters.)
>
> ...
>
> If the declarator or type specifier that declares the identifier
>   appears within the list of parameter declarations in a function
>   prototype (not part of a function definition), the identifier has
>   function prototype scope, which terminates at the end of the function
>   declarator.

GCC 4.6.1 gives a nice warning about this for me:

```
C:\temp\test.c:3:22: warning: 'struct node' declared inside parameter list [enabled by default]
C:\temp\test.c:3:22: warning: its scope is only this definition or declaration, which is probably not what you want [enabled by default]
```

C++ makes function prototype scope apply only to the parameter names (C++03 3.3.3), so you won't see this problem if you compile the code as C++.

Answer (score 2):

remove the extern from the header.
When you declare a function as external, you guide the compiler that the function is not going to be compiled, and any reference to that function will be resolved in the linkage.
Usually, this declaration is done when working with pre compiled libraries.

Comment: hey i removed the extern from header but still geting same error ,another thing ,is the error due to the function parameter **struct node *k ** ?. in neither source code nor in header file i have defined **struct node ** , which is defined in different source code

Comment: This is quite strange, try to clean up and recompile again. What you describe shouldn't cause the same error. Beside, always include the structures definition where you use it...

Comment: Why would that matter? I believe this answer is incorrect. 6.2.2 "If the declaration of an identifier for a function has no storage-class specifier, its linkage
is determined exactly as if it were declared with the storage-class specifier extern. If the declaration of an identifier for an object has file scope and no storage-class specifier, its linkage is external."

Answer (score 1):

In your test2.h you have declared `f` as `extern`, that's why you are getting the error. In test.c there is no `extern` declaration in prototype.

Comment: hey i removed the extern from header but still geting same error ,another thing ,is the error due to the function parameter **struct node *k ** ?. in neither source code nor in header file i have defined **struct node ** , which is defined in different source code

Comment: In that case you need to declare `struct node` as extern.

Comment: where do i need to declare it , means in test2.h or in test.c. and just write down the declaration , i am confused what i need to declare.

Comment: In test2.h add `extern struct node;`.

Comment: This is test2.h:
`extern struct node;
void f(struct node * k);`

Comment: thanx alot taskinoor for your help, but i have one doubt that if i dont include header file test2.h and declare function prototype in test.c , i can compile , where i dont have any declaration regarding structure **struct node**.

Comment: Why would that matter? I believe this answer is incorrect. 6.2.2 "If the declaration of an identifier for a function has no storage-class specifier, its linkage
is determined exactly as if it were declared with the storage-class specifier extern. If the declaration of an identifier for an object has file scope and no storage-class specifier, its linkage is external."