# C error: conflicting types for function and previous declaration was here (not duplicate)

Tags: c, arrays, function

Apologies for the dumb question. I checked all similar questions for the same error on stackoverflow, but it didn't help me understand why this error is happening in the following code.

I have one additional header file and a source file, which is included in the main file, and when I compile, I am getting the following error. I am trying to pass the `char** argv` from the `main()` to another function defined in another header file.

```
#include "include/Process.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
if (argc < 2) {
    printf("Please provide a path to file\n");
    return (EXIT_FAILURE);
}
Process(argv);
```

Process.h:

```
#pragma once
extern void Process(char** path);
```

Process.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "../include/Process.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <syslog.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
void Process(char** path) {
    printf("%s\n", path[1]);
}
```

It gets compiled but the warning is

```
./src/Process.c:22:6: error: conflicting types for ‘Process’
 void Process(char** path) {
      ^
./include/Process.h:17:6: note: previous declaration of ‘Process’ was here
 extern void Process(char** path);
  ^
```

However, the warning disappears when I change the type of `path` from `char**` to `char*` and pass `argv[1]` instead of `argv`.

I am clueless why this is happening like this, and according to 
[this similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9323905/error-conflicting-types-for-f-and-previous-declaration-of-f-was-here), I tried adding a forward declaration for `char** path` above `extern void Process(char** path);` in the `Process.h` file, but it didn't help either.

- Why is this error thrown when using `char** path`?
- Why it disappears when I use `char* path`?
- So far, I am able to see the program running, even with this warning. Is it safe to ignore this warning? If not, what could be the possible effects it can have during runtime?

Using gcc version 4.9.2 (Ubuntu 4.9.2-10ubuntu13)

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps your compiler doesn't understand the non-standard `#pragma once`. Try to replace it with `#ifndef MYPROCESS_H #define MYPROCESS_H ... #endif`.

Comment: All those includes, and you forgot to include `stdio.h` for `printf` :)? What's the exact command you're using to compile? Does it still happen if you only compile (and no link) `Process.c` (e.g. `cc -c Process.c`)?

Comment: Thank you @Lundin, tried that, but it didn't help me with this warning.

Comment: @Cornstalks Thank you for the suggestion. Yes, I tried with and without linking. I am compiling it with gcc -Wall ./main.c ./src/Process.c -c (with and without c), and it is still giving me the warning. And sorry, the stdio.h  was there in the file, but a bit on top of other includes, so I missed when copy-pasting it here :)

Comment: Which version of gcc? And does it still happen if you remove all those `#include`s in Process.c (except `stdio.h`; you need that one) (I'm curious if one of them is defining something that's conflicting with Process, and the compiler's reporting is maybe buggy)?

Comment: Couldn't reproduce.

Comment: Unable to reproduce on Visual Studio 2010 (had to remove `#include <syslog.h>` and `#include <unistd.h>`, and add `#include <stdio.h>`).

Comment: @Cornstalks using gcc version 4.9.2 (Ubuntu 4.9.2-10ubuntu13). Tried removing all other includes except stdio.h, but the warning is still happening.

Comment: I can't reproduce this either, but it most likely has something to do with the compiler thinking that the declaration and definition  are in different translation units. That is, goofed up includes, paths or similar.

Comment: The message says the error is on line 22 of Process.c, but that file only has 10 lines

Comment: Try putting your custom includes after all the standard includes

Comment: @M.M There were some comments added by the netbeans IDE on top of that file and hence the extra lines. Line 22 is void Process(char** path) {

Comment: Try to make a [MCVE] stripping all `#includes` except `#include "Process.h"`.

Comment: @M.M Your last solution removed the warning. I tried including it after the standard include, and now there is no warnings. Why does it matter? Could you give it as an answer and why it is caused, and if it is safe to ignore? I am more than happy to accept it as an answer.

Comment: Wait, you're saying that moving the Process.h include *below* the other system includes fixed this issue? But removing the system includes didn't? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: @MichaelWalz M.M's comment to put the custom include after the standard include removed the warning, although I have no idea why it mattered :) How could this be figured out from the warning that gcc threw? Is there a rule of thumb for the includes order?

Comment: @scott actually in your question you mentioned a _warning_ but is is actually an _error_.

Comment: @scott general rule of thumb: include system headers first and then your headers. At least that's what I always do.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Thank you, I will remember that. And why is it so? I am a bit curious why the order of includes caused this error, when the function itself was declared after all the includes?

Comment: @scott hard to tell what the exact problem was here. Now why should your own headers be included after th system headers: I suggest you to ask a new question about this.

Comment: Thank you @MichaelWalz, Much appreciate it. I just tested this on a different computer with a gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.2), and there the same code that errored above got compiled without the error.

Comment: Could `Process` be defined as a macro somewhere? Try this. Start with a copy of your existing code. Remove chunks of code until the problem goes away. Narrow it down to as small a modification as possible that eliminates the error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting your custom includes after the system includes.

It might be possible that the custom include defines a macro which interferes with the system includes. To minimize the risk of this, I always put the Standard C includes first, then any OS includes, and then third party libraries, and then my own ones

In *theory* the custom include shouldn't do this, and the system includes should only use reserved names, but in practice this doesn't always happen.