# Is typedef allowed before definition

Tags: c, clang, iwyu

Minimum code:

```cpp
// foo.h

typedef struct foo_s foo_t;

struct foo_s {
  foo_t* next;
};
```

`iwyu` insists I forward declare `struct foo_s` before I `typedef` it to `foo_t`.

Output:

```sh
$ iwyu -c foo.h 

foo.h should add these lines:
struct foo_s;

foo.h should remove these lines:

The full include-list for foo.h:
struct foo_s;
---
```

This is true across different versions of `iwyu`, including newer versions with `-Xiwyu --no_fwd_decls` added.

Is this a mistake in `iwyu` or does the `C` standard want me to define the type before the `typedef`?

Comment: Looks like `iwyu` bug to me.

Comment: The C standard allows it. But if your tool doesn't allow it, then you need to do what the tool allows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> does the C standard want me to define the type before the `typedef`?

It does not. The standard verbiage is as follows

> **6.7.2.3 Tags**
>
> [7](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.3p7) A declaration of the form
>
> ```
>       struct-or-union identifier ;
> ```
>
> specifies a structure or union type and declares the identifier as a
>   tag of that type.
>
> [8](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.3p8) If a type specifier of the form
>
> ```
>       struct-or-union identifier
> ```
>
> occurs other than as part of one of the above forms, and no other
>   declaration of the identifier as a tag is visible, then it declares an
>   incomplete structure or union type, and declares the identifier as the
>   tag of that type.

So your original pair of declarations has well-defined behavior. The declaration for the structure is implicitly added into the translation unit at the point you define the type alias, and then completed afterward. The fact that the tool does not allow it may be due to a bug, a limitation of the tool, or perhaps an attempt to enforce a particular coding style.

---

There is one point in favor of the style that the tool may try to enforce, and it has to do with the C notion of scope. Specifically, function parameter list scope. As an example, [see this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9323905/error-conflicting-types-for-f-and-previous-declaration-of-f-was-here) and refer to this short example

```
void bar(struct foo);

struct foo {
    char c;
};

void bar(struct foo f) {}
```

It so happens that the first declaration of `bar` is declared with a type that is unique to its parameter list. The initial declaration of `struct foo` is not the same type as the one used in the later function definition. As such, the code 
will not compile by a conforming C compiler. Declaring the structure on its own line ahead of the first function declaration fixes this problem.

Answer (score 1):

This [C11 Draft Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) makes it quite clear that you can 'forward declare' a `typedef struct...`, by way of an example that is *very* similar to your code:

> **6.7.2.3 Tags**
>  ...
>  11 The following alternative formulation uses the **typedef** mechanism:
>
> ```
> typedef struct tnode TNODE;
> struct tnode {
>     int count;
>     TNODE *left, *right;
> };
> TNODE s, *sp;
> ```

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug.  It seems the typedef for a structure is considered the same way as a typedef for an enumeration.

For enumerations you may not use an incomplete type in a typedef definition

From the C Standard (6.7.2.3 Tags)

> 3 A type specifier of the form

```
enum identifier
```

> without an enumerator list shall only appear after the type it
>   specifies is complete.

So for example such a typedef

```
typedef enum E AnotherE;

enum E { N };
```

is invalid while this typedef

```
enum E { N };

typedef enum E AnotherE;
```

is valid.

For structures you may use an incomplete type in a typedef definition.

> 8 If a type specifier of the form

```
struct-or-union identifier
```

> occurs other than as part of one of the above forms, and no other
>   declaration of the identifier as a tag is visible, then it declares an
>   incomplete structure or union type, and declares the identifier as the
>   tag of that type.